# ¿Cómo hago para que mi método acumule un dato sin que el ciclo lo regrese a cero?

Tags: java

Para empezar, aclaro que estoy usando java ya que es un programa para un curso de la universidad. El enunciado pide hacer un programa que calcule el aumento de un salario base al 3% por 3 años —esta parte sí se realiza bien— y que sume el salario de cada año usando el ciclo repetitivo for. El caso es que el ciclo esta devolviendo el valor acumulativo a cero cada vez que el ciclo for itera y al final solo imprime el último aumento del salario.

```
        public class Salario {

            double salario_anual_media;

        public void Intercambio(double vsalariociclo)
        {
            salario_anual_media = vsalariociclo;
        }
        public double Ciclo_Incremental()
        {
                double salario_anual;
                salario_anual = salario_anual_media + (salario_anual_media*0.03);
                return salario_anual;
        }
        public double SalarioTotal(double salario_anual)
    {
        double salario_total=0;
        salario_total = (salario_total + salario_anual);
        return salario_total;
    }



        public static void main (String []args)
{
    int i;
    double vsalario_inicial = 1500, vsalariociclo, salario_anual=0, salario_total=0; 
    System.out.println("PROGRAMA PARA CALCULAR EL AUMENTO DE SALARIO ANUAL");
    Salario sl = new Salario();
    vsalariociclo = vsalario_inicial;

    for (i = 0; i<3; i++)
    {
        sl.Intercambio(vsalariociclo);
        salario_anual = sl.Ciclo_Incremental();
            sl.SalarioTotal(salario_anual); 
        salario_total = sl.SalarioTotal(salario_anual); 
        System.out.printf("\nSalario año %d: %.2f", i+1, salario_anual);

        vsalariociclo = salario_anual;  

    }
    System.out.printf("\n\nEl incremento total del salario en 3 años es de: %.2f", salario_total);
}
}
```

Comment: Me cuesta trabajo entender cual es el error, podrías ser un poco más detallado?

Comment: Pasa que el método para sumar los incrementos del salario en 3 años no está acumulando los incrementos anuales, al final de la ultima iteración del for solo guarda el ultimo incremento y es lo que imprime en el ultimo mensaje.

Comment: ósea que está linea ` System.out.printf("\nSalario año %d: %.2f", i+1, salario_anual);` no está funcionando? o cómo que solo guarda, en dónde exactamente?

Comment: Esa línea esta funcionando correctamente, el punto es que dentro del ciclo, la variable salario_total no se esta acumulando, esa variable debe mostrar la sumatoria del incremento durante los 3 años en el mensaje 'System.out.printf("\n\nEl incremento total del salario en 3 años es de: %.2f", salario_total);'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me parece que el error es que estás igualando en lugar de estar sumando, intenta con

`salario_total += sl.SalarioTotal(salario_anual);`

Donde el `+=` indica la suma de lo que vale más el nuevo valor